# Tomcat MemoryRealm Authentication at jsp:include

Tags: tomcat, basic-authentication

I want to authenticate a user, when a jsp is included.
I got

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />
```

in my server.xml
and

```
<role rolename="testuser" />
```

`<user name="test" password="test" roles="testuser" />`

in the tomcat-user.xml

Now my problem with the include:
I want that the login form pops up, wenn the jsp /modules/administration/admininstation.jsp
is included by

```
<jsp:include page="modules/administration/administration.jsp" flush="true"/>
```

Is there a way to do this?
I couldn´t find a url-pattern that matches. Or does tomcat not recognize the include as an request? errrrr I don´t understand that!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication happens at the start of every request. `jsp:include` does a server side include (= there isn't any new request from the browser to the Tomcat), so there is not a second authentication before the `jsp:include`. If the client has access to the original page she will see the included jsp too.

You may should send a redirect to the browser ([hint](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29)) and you may also need to set properly the `security-constraint` and the `login-config` tags in the `web.xml`.